# Confused about 2 Laravel Eloquent calls

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

So I have been making a web app based on a bunch of tutorials I followed to make a basic CMS. But now I'm working on my own project.

I am making some more spefic eloquent calls, and I'm not sure why this is not working as good.

```php
$session = \App\Sessions::where('user_id', '=', \Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('task_type', '=', 'Match Pictures')
    ->where('status', '=', 'started')->get();

return $session->session_id;
```

but when I return:

```php
return $session
```

I see all the data in an array.

But I've been using this for my tutorial app that worked.

```php
  $articles = Article::latest('published_at')->published()->get();

  return $article->title;
```

So why does the first one not work, but the second one does? And how can I do this?

**Edit**

Error message I  get

> ErrorException in MatchPictures.php line 27: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$session_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get` returns a collection, so you can't access any properties on it directly.

Instead of `get`, use `first` to get a single model. Then your code above should work.

---

Alternatively, you can use the `value` method, which does the same thing:

```php
return App\Sessions::where([
    'user_id'   => auth()->id(),
    'task_type' => 'Match Pictures',
    'status'    => 'started',
])->value('session_id');
```

Comment: When I do this I get an ErrorException in MatchPictures.php line 27: Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: I updated to show my original error. Is it because I havent set my hasmany or hasone functions? I only have my fillables set.

Comment: You haven't shown us your code in MatchPictures.php line 27, so I can't help you with that.

Comment: line 27 is the last line of the query. "  ->where('status', '=', 'started')->get();"

Comment: I tried using first. And yes it works. But to double check this would only work to get the first row. If there are more rows, it's only fetching the first row right?

Comment: @JPFoster - Correct. Since you only want a single value, `value` will return a single value. If you want a collection of values, use `lists('session_id')` instead.

Comment: Well this was just a test. I will need all the columns in the table. Will first still work?